# What are the reasons for using Ragel to parse strings in a C++ codebase?

Tags: c++, ragel

I inherited a C++ project which uses Ragel for string parsing.

This is the first time I have seen this being done and I would like to understand why someone would use Ragel instead of C++ to parse a string?

Comment: Perhaps because it is some parser generator which is simple to use?

Comment: Basically what you are asking is what the benefits are of using a library such as Ragel for string parsing, instead of rolling your own implementation in plain c++?

Comment: Did you read [Ragel intro](http://www.colm.net/open-source/ragel/)? Alternatives might be [flex](https://github.com/westes/flex), [bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/), [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/)

Comment: @gurka I've never come across Ragel before so it is completely new to me. Found it odd in a strictly c++ codebase

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thank you. Are there other common alternatives to Ragel?

Comment: Why do people use C++ instead of C? Why do people use C instead of assembly?  I can write my own string lexing code but ragel (or re2c, etc) does it better, faster, and with fewer bugs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[parser generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler-compiler) (improperly called "compiler-compilers") are very handsome to use and produce reliable and efficient C++ or C code (notably because [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) theory is well understood).

In general, using source code generators could be a wise thing to do. Sometimes, notably in large projects, it is sensible to write your own one (read about [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming), notably [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) and even [J.Pitrat's blog](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/)). Good [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tools like [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [ninja](http://ninja-build.org/) can easily be configured to run C or C++ code generators and use them at build time.

Read [Ragel](http://www.colm.net/open-source/ragel/) intro. Look also into [flex](http://www.gnu.org/software/flex/), [bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/), [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/), [rpcgen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPCGEN), [Qt moc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/moc.html), [swig](http://swig.org/), [gperf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/) as common examples of C or C++ generators.

In some programs, you could even use some [JIT compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) library (such as [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/) or [LLVM](http://llvm.org/)) to dynamically generate code at run time and use it. On POSIX systems you could also generate at runtime a temporary C or C++ file, compile it as a [plugin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)), and load that temporary plugin using [dlopen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlopen.html) & [dlsym](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html). Having a good culture about compilers and interpreters (e.g. thru the [Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools)) is then worthwhile.

Embedding some interpreter (like [lua](http://lua.org/) or [guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/)) in your application is also an interesting approach. But it is a strong architectural decision.

In many cases, generating source code is easier than hand writing it. Of course that is not always possible.

<sup>PS. I never heard of Ragel before reading your question!</sup>